# How can I render a ClickableTextCell as an anchor in a GWT CellTable?

Tags: gwt, anchor, cell

I've got a CellTable with multiple columns in simple TextCell()s.  Two of the columns are 'clickable' via the ClickableTextCell() class, but I want to change how they look.  What's the easiest way to get the cell contents to resemble an anchor tag, while still using a cell in the table?

I've tried the following:
  1. Implement a custom renderer to add anchor tags
  2. Scouring Google looking for hints
  3. Ignoring 'my library does it you just have to change your entire framework' links
  4. Rolling my head across they keyboard

It's funny how annoying this simple change is turning out to be.

My current thought is to implement a custom AnchorCell type which puts in an Anchor widget instead of whatever it does in the other ones, but I'm not sure what all would need to be done.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an example:

```
public class MyClickableCellText extends ClickableTextCell {

    String style;   
    public MyClickableCellText()
    {
        super();
        style = "myClickableCellTestStyle";
    }


     @Override
      protected void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div class=\""+style+"\">");
          sb.append(value);
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
        }
      }

     public void addStyleName(String style)
     {
         this.style = style; 
     }


}
```

And the style (without the div, because you are hardcoding the style on it):

```
.myClickableCellTestStyle{
    text-decoration:underline;

}
```

You can even create your own cell by not extending ClickableTextCell but extending AbstractCell (more powerful but need more explanation). Ask me if you need it!

Comment: I haven't gotten back to this yet! Looks promising! Thanks!

Comment: Where is the click action?  This seems like an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 5):

Mentioned solution have the problem, these are no links and stylesheets with a:hover and so on doesn't work.

Here is my solution:

```
private class SellerName {
    private final String sellerName;
    private final Command cmd;

    private SellerName(String displayName, Command cmd) {
      this.sellerName = displayName;
      this.cmd = cmd;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
      return sellerName;
    }

    public Command getCommand() {
        return cmd;
    }
};

private class SellerNameCell extends AbstractCell<SellerName> {

    public SellerNameCell() {
        super("click", "keydown");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, SellerName value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
         if (value != null) {
             sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a href='javascript:;'>");
             sb.appendEscaped(value.getDisplayName());
             sb.appendHtmlConstant("</a>");
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, SellerName value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<SellerName> valueUpdater) {
        if (value == null)
            return;

        super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
        if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
            if (value.getCommand() != null)
                value.getCommand().execute();
        }
    }
};
```

It creates a real anchorcell which is clickable :)

Comment: Oh what a lifesaver!!

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that your first instinct (implementing a custom renderer) is way easier:

```
SafeHtmlRenderer<String> anchorRenderer = new AbstractSafeHtmlRenderer<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml render(String object) {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a href=\"javascript:;\">")
                    .appendEscaped(object).appendHtmlConstant("</a>");
            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
```

And then:

```
Column<YourThingy, String> anchorCol = new Column<YourThingy, String>(
            new ClickableTextCell(anchorRenderer))
    {

        @Override
        public String getValue(YourThingy object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need:

```
public class ClickableSafeHtmlCell extends AbstractCell<SafeHtml> {
/**
 * Construct a new ClickableSafeHtmlCell.
 */
public ClickableSafeHtmlCell() {
    super("click", "keydown");
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, SafeHtml value, NativeEvent event,
        ValueUpdater<SafeHtml> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
        onEnterKeyDown(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onEnterKeyDown(Context context, Element parent, SafeHtml value,
        NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<SafeHtml> valueUpdater) {
    if (valueUpdater != null) {
        valueUpdater.update(value);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
        sb.append(value);
    }
}
```

And then usage:

```
Column<YourProxy, SafeHtml> nameColumn = new Column<YourProxy, SafeHtml>(
        new ClickableSafeHtmlCell()) {
    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(YourProxy object) {
        SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a>");
        sb.appendEscaped(object.getName());
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</a>");
        return sb.toSafeHtml();
    }
};

nameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<YourProxy, SafeHtml>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, YourProxy object, SafeHtml value) {
             Window.alert("You have clicked: " + object.getName());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Without an href an the anchor, it appears only as blue text in Chrome. The href suggested by @thomas of "href='javascript:;'" seems to help.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite simple, but it's amazing how many wrong and convoluted answers there are on Google, and seemingly no correct ones! Anyway, here's the code:

```
private Column<Object, SafeHtml> getAnchorColumn() {
    return new Column<Object, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(final Object object) {
            Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
            anchor.setHref(object.getURL());
            anchor.setText(object.getText());

            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            sb.appendHtmlConstant(anchor.toString());
            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
}
```

Change object to whatever it is you're trying to render in the table then run this method when creating the column, easy!

Comment: You'll want to use `anchor.getElement().getString()`- I've had Javascript debug output come up with `a.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look to the clickableTextCell html code generated by gwt you will see something like (taken from gwt showcase)

```
<div style="outline:none;" tabindex="0">Click Robert</div>
```

So I will recommend u doing something like:

```
ClickableTextCell cell = new ClickableTextCell();
cell.addStyleName("yourStyle");
```

and in you style.css do whatever you want.

```
.yourStyle div{

text-decoration:underline;

}
```

Comment: Only ClickableTextCell has no such method.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean you can use it directly. You need to create your own ClickableTextCell implementation. Override onRender() and do sb.append(<div>);s

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially a hack to use `appendHtmlConstant`. Simply using `toString` of the `Anchor` or its element or passing a HTML string violates the concept behind `SafeHtml` entirely.

In my opinion a proper `SafeHtmlTemplates` should be used to tackle unreadable and unsafe string concatenation of HTML. Similar to:

```java
protected interface AnchorTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>")
    SafeHtml anchor(String url, String text);
}
```

Then you can use `GWT.create` on it and interpolate the arguments properly.

Second part is that reading the HTML string of a widget could be optimized out. I was extending `AbstractCell` and had this method:

```java
/* do not dare to copy - considered broken */
@Override
public void render(final Context context, final String value, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    final Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
    anchor.setText(value);
    sb.appendHtmlConstant(anchor.getElement().toString());
}
```

I just experienced a case where the anchor cell was working fine in superdev mode, but compiling it (probably with more aggressive optimization settings) and then deploying it manually led to an entirely empty cell with no changes in code reproducibly across several systems. Using the template mechanism described above made it work properly (GWT 2.7).

Answer (score 0):

First things first - each GWT CellTable Column is just a stack of Cell(s), as our need is to make each Cell look like an anchor which can listen to Click event lets provide ClickableTextCell as argument to Column.

```
Column<YourObj, String> col = new Column<YourObj, String>(new ClickableTextCell()) {};
```

2nd - override "render()" method in your Column instance and build your HTML template that you want, here our need is creating an anchor.

```
@Override
        public void render(Context context, YourObj yourObj, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;'>" + yourObj.getX() + "</a>");
        }
```

3rd - as we are using ClickableTextCell, it serves as Click Event source. We need to provide ClickEvent listener, we do that by overriding "onBrowserEvent()" method.

```
@Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, Customer customer, NativeEvent event) {
            if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
                Window.alert("ID is : " + customer.getId());
            }
        }
```

Complete Code snippet :

```
Column<YourObj, String> col = new Column<YourObj, String>(new ClickableTextCell()) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(final YourObj yourObj) {
            return yourObj.getX();
        }

        @Override
        public void render(Context context, YourObj yourObj, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a style='text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;'>" + yourObj.getX() + "</a>");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, YourObj yourObj, NativeEvent event) {
            if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
                Window.alert("ID is : " + yourObj.getId());
            }
        }
    };
```

cellTable.addColumn(col, "First Name");