# How can I put a widget in a CellTable Cell?

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I am using CellTable to show my records but now the thing is I want show a select box when user clicks on a cell. One more thing is that select box is my own widget, not a predefined. Can you please suggest to me any method of doing this?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Comment: I have the same problem - I need to render some fairly heavyweight widgets (in terms of their logic) into cells in a table. What I wanted from CellTable was to be able to supply an IsWidget factory to be used to generate the widget for rendering each cell in a column. I can't see an easy way to do this but I'd rather not implement tables from scratch.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a post on the GWT google group that discusses [the answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/nPtKO1xK8L4/4zetZLJgRnUJ).  Basically you create your custom widget as normal, and inside the render function you use widget.getElement().getInnterHTML().

```
@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
             MyWidget widget = new MyWidget(value);
             sb.appendEscaped(widget.getElement.getInnerHTML()); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using widget.getElement.getInnerHTML(), I'm using widget.getElement.getString(), because it includes the outer HTML.

Comment: is it possible to reuse the same widget to render the HTML for each cell? (i should probably just write some code to find out..but just intrigued..)

Answer (score 10):

This is an anti-pattern. The whole purpose of cells is so that you do NOT have widgets: you are supposed to "render" html directly in the cell.

Comment: why did they add UIBinder widget support to celltables then? (not exactly a citation but from the thread: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/9cfb4a3b5c4af0be/b75305d15a1c32e8?lnk=gst&q=celltable+widget#b75305d15a1c32e8)

Comment: might be, but sometimes inevitable

Comment: I disagree, sometimes you don't want to bother with HTML, and just let GWT render widgets for you.

Answer (score 7):

> There's a post on the GWT google group that discusses the answer. Basically you create your custom widget as normal, and inside the render function you use widget.getElement().getInnterHTML().

```
@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
         MyWidget widget = new MyWidget(value);
         sb.appendEscaped(widget.getElement.getInnerHTML()); 
    }
}
```

It works but there is a limitation:

- You **CAN'T** attach any handler directly on your widget (outer or inner).

eg:

```
widget.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Won't work!!!
    }
});
```

or:

```
widget.getMyTextBox().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Won't work!!!
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for this limitation? I really want to implement such a funcitonality.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691801/how-can-i-render-a-clickabletextcell-as-an-anchor-in-a-gwt-celltable

look at the answer by 'thomas'

Comment: Be aware the click event will be triggered whenever **anything** in the column is clicked. If you have two buttons in the column, you won't be able to distinguish between which is clicked. In this case refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108317/gwt-celltable-need-to-have-two-buttons-in-last-single-cell-of-each-row.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I faced with the similar problem (tried to insert a custom widget into CellList cell), but unfortunately did not find an easy solution.

Generally, you can implement specific cell class, extending [AbstractCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html) or [ActionCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ActionCell.html). In this case you will have to override render() method and implement your own rendering. Good example is given in [AbstractCell class javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think @Kel has given the closest answer , I use his answer and I found `ActionCell` can use `IdentityColumn` and `CellTable` Can use `IdentityColumn`

```
ActionCell<MyEntity> refreshCell = new ActionCell<>("Refresh", new ActionCell.Delegate<MyEntity>() {

  @Override
  public void execute(MyEntity entity) {
    //bla bla bla
  }
});
IdentityColumn<MyEntity> refreshColumn = new IdentityColumn<>(refreshCell);
cellTable.addColumn(refreshColumn, "Refresh");
```