# GWT CellTable-Need to have two buttons in last single cell of each row

Tags: gwt

I am using CellTable to add columns to it.
It works fine when I add rows and single data on each cell.

It has header like Name ,Age, Address with rows below it which contains the values

I now want to have a Actions cloumn in the last with two buttons (Edit and Delete Button) in single cell in on the rows below this column and to capture the button click events acordingly.

```
Name Age Address   Actions
A    15    123    Edit Delete
B    20    578    Edit Delete    
C
```

Could you please let me know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to achieve that:

1. Subclass [AbstractCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html) and implement the render method to create two buttons and handle its events (see [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html) for more details).
2. Use a [CompositeCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html) to add two [ActionCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html)s

Second approach is easier and cleaner. Here is the code for that:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    CellTable<Person> table = new CellTable<Person>();

    List<HasCell<Person, ?>> cells = new LinkedList<HasCell<Person, ?>>();
    cells.add(new ActionHasCell("Edit", new Delegate<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Person object) {
           // EDIT CODE
        }
    }));
    cells.add(new ActionHasCell("Delete", new Delegate<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Person object) {
            // DELETE CODE
        }
    }));

    CompositeCell<Person> cell = new CompositeCell<Person>(cells);
    table.addColumn(new TextColumn<Person>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Person object) {
            return object.getName()
        }
    }, "Name");

    // ADD Cells for Age and Address

    table.addColumn(new Column<Person, Person>(cell) {

        @Override
        public Person getValue(Person object) {
            return object;
        }
    }, "Actions");


}

private class ActionHasCell implements HasCell<Person, Person> {
    private ActionCell<Person> cell;

    public ActionHasCell(String text, Delegate<Person> delegate) {
        cell = new ActionCell<Person>(text, delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Cell<Person> getCell() {
        return cell;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldUpdater<Person, Person> getFieldUpdater() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getValue(Person object) {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, As I m new biew to GWT...its been a great help. But I am not able to find any deleteRow method in the cellTable.... Could you please let me know how to delete particular row on which delete has been clicked.

Comment: basically you have to remove it from the ``ListDataProvider`` to which you add the CellTable as a Display. So as soon as you remove the item from the ``ListDataProvider`` the CellTable will be refreshed.

Comment: I get an error on  public ActionHasCell(String text, Delegate<HikingMeals> delegate) { - Multiple markers at this line
 - The type Delegate is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
  <HikingMeals>
 - The type Delegate is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
  <HikingMeals>

Answer (score 1):

The solution above is perfect!THX.
In addition: If you liked to design the buttons in the ActionCell, then you could do this -> In the constructon of the class you can build a html input and in "class" attribute, you can add a css style, which will be used.:

```
public ActionHasCell(String text, Delegate<Person> delegate) {
        cell = new ActionCell<Person>(text, delegate) {

        public void render(Context context, Person person, SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
        {
            SafeHtml html = SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString("<input type=\"button\" value=\"anynameyouwant\" class=\"cssstylename\" />");
            sb.append(html);
        }

    };
}
```

This time you don't need the String, but you can pass parameters and use them to build the button.