# Adding Hyperlink in GWT celltable

Tags: gwt

I am trying to add a hyperlink in celltable and on clicking on that link i want to call a method.

with the below code i am getting a hyperlink in my celltable correctly but I am not able to call  a method by clicking on the link , when i click the link it takes me to the previous page.

Any Solution

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Delete","");

Column<EmployerJobs, Hyperlink> linkColumn = 
    new Column<EmployerJobs, Hyperlink>(new HyperLinkCell()) { 
      @Override 
      public Hyperlink getValue(EmployerJobs list) {
        link.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            deleteJobs(list);
          }
        });
        return link; 
      }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a HyperlinkCell you can either use a [ClickableTextCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ClickableTextCell.html), a ButtonCell or an [ActionCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ActionCell.html).

**ClickableTextCell**:

```
Column<EmployerJobs, String> linkColumn = 
    new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(new ClickableTextCell())  {
         @Override
         public String getValue(EmployerJobs object)  {
             return TEXT_TO_DISPLAY;
         }
    },'linkheadertext');
linkColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<EmployerJobs, String>() {
         @Override
         public void update(int index, EmployerJobs object, String value) {
             deleteJobs(object);
         }
});
```

**ButtonCell**:

```
Column<EmployerJobs, String> buttonColumn = 
    new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(new ButtonCell())  {
         @Override
         public String getValue(EmployerJobs object)  {
             return TEXT_TO_DISPLAY;
         }
    },'linkheadertext');
buttonColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<EmployerJobs, String>() {
         @Override
         public void update(int index, EmployerJobs object, String value) {
             deleteJobs(object);
         }
});
```

**ActionCell**:

```
Column<EmployerJobs, EmployerJobs> actionColumn = 
    new Column<EmployerJobs, EmployerJobs>(new ActionCell<EmployerJobs>("Click Me",
        new ActionCell.Delegate<EmployerJobs>() {
            @Override
            public void execute(EmployerJobs jobs) {
                deleteJobs(jobs);
            }
        })
    {
         @Override
         public EmployerJobs getValue(EmployerJobs object)  {
             return object;
         }
    },'linkheadertext');
```

Check out the CellSample [showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) for more infos.

Answer (score 3):

I have post my answer on the similar thread:
[How can I render a ClickableTextCell as an anchor in a GWT CellTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691801/how-can-i-render-a-clickabletextcell-as-an-anchor-in-a-gwt-celltable)
but for those who bookmarked this thread:
This is what you need

```
public class ClickableSafeHtmlCell extends AbstractCell<SafeHtml> {
/**
 * Construct a new ClickableSafeHtmlCell.
 */
public ClickableSafeHtmlCell() {
    super("click", "keydown");
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, SafeHtml value, NativeEvent event,
        ValueUpdater<SafeHtml> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
        onEnterKeyDown(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onEnterKeyDown(Context context, Element parent, SafeHtml value,
        NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<SafeHtml> valueUpdater) {
    if (valueUpdater != null) {
        valueUpdater.update(value);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value != null) {
        sb.append(value);
    }
}
```

And then usage:

```
Column<YourProxy, SafeHtml> nameColumn = new Column<YourProxy, SafeHtml>(
        new ClickableSafeHtmlCell()) {
    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(YourProxy object) {
        SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<a>");
        sb.appendEscaped(object.getName());
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</a>");
        return sb.toSafeHtml();
    }
};

nameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<YourProxy, SafeHtml>() {
        @Override
        public void update(int index, YourProxy object, SafeHtml value) {
             Window.alert("You have clicked: " + object.getName());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in above answer you can use updater when you want inplace editing. But if you want to capture a click to perform some action, you can do it using ClickableTextCell.

```
ClickableTextCell employerJobsCell = new ClickableTextCell();

Column<EmployerJobs, String> employerJobsColumn = new Column<EmployerJobs, String>(employerJobsCell) {    
    @Override
    public String getValue(EmployerJobs object) {
        return object.getWhichStringToDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, EmployerJobs object, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        //this method is optional, can be used if the display needs to be customized
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, EmployerJobs object, NativeEvent event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(context, elem, object, event);

        Event evt = Event.as(event);
        int eventType = evt.getTypeInt();
        if (eventType == Event.ONCLICK) {
            //call delete job when cell is clicked
            deleteJobs(object);
        }
    }
};
```

dataGrid.addColumn(employerJobsColumn, "The header goes here");

Comment: but when i will click on cliclable text cell , hyperlink wil be clicked as well and it will go that previous page again